# Click Instantiated Object and Return What it's number C#(UNITY)

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I don't know actually what to search on google so I directly get here and I am sorry about that . My problem is that I have `Instantiate()` objects like this

```
public void InstantiateObject(){
//the list has 5 objects in it .
  for (int i = 0; i < list.Count; i++)
  {
    GameObject o = Instantiate(lobby_object) as GameObject;
    o.transform.SetParent(pos_lobby_object);
    o.transform.localScale = Vector3.one;

    o.transform.name = "spr_boards " + lobby_object_no;

    o.transform.localPosition = new Vector3(0, 0, 0);
    NGUITools.SetActive(o, true);
  }
}
```

The output of that would be

> spr_boards 1
>
> spr_boards 2
>
> spr_boards 3
>
> spr_boards 4
>
> spr_boards 5

I have a click event by the way on another script

```
public void InstantiateTheObject(){
      fromAnotherScript.InstantiateObject();
}
```

Then drag this `InstantiateTheObject` to the button on the inspector

Now I want to click one of this object and return what number are they
but I don't know how to do it .

EDIT:

More information

If i clicked the Instantiated `spr_board 1` for example this must log for example a "this is object 1";

then if i click `spr_board 2` for example this must log for example a "this is object 2`;

I tried this

```
public void InstantiateTheObject(){
   Debug.Log("objects number is : " + lobby_object_no);
      fromAnotherScript.InstantiateObject();
}
```

but the problem is that it always get the last value of my last . It's not depending on what I click on the instantiated object.

Comment: Well, you can just find the space, and get the number after it from a string

Comment: well you are making 5 identical things and placing them over the top of each others, so I guess the last one is on top

Comment: The order of the list i have actually is `1,5,3,2,4` so the bottom is always selected . So it is 4 always @BugFinder.

Comment: what exactly then are you struggling with (despite the deleted comment) it seems your problem is you get a different object on clicking to what you expected

Comment: I'm struggling on having an exact output of each object for example i click the first instantiated object then it must be `spr_boards 1` then logs a "this is object 1"; and so on

Comment: but we explained how to get the number, so again, what specifically are you struggling with

Comment: I edited my question sir @BugFinder

Comment: Ok so this has nothing to do with click or anything..  While its not clear in your code where lobby_object_no comes from, Im going to guess that it says 5 because thats the last value assigned to it, not the one from the object, hence, we have explained how to get the number from the name of the object (PS I am NOT male)

Comment: Attach the `MeshDetector` from the duplicate to the prefab "lobby_object" GameObject. When instantiated, and clicked on, it should how you the name. I assume you're using a 3D Object so see the **#6** from the duplicate If you're using something else then check the rest of the answer from the duplicate

Comment: Wow thank you programmer

Comment: You're welcome!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

how to get number from transform name:

```
RaycastHit hit;
 void Update()
 {
    if (Input.GetMouseButtonDown (0))
    {
       Ray ray = Camera.main.ScreenPointToRay(Input.mousePosition);
       if(Physics.Raycast(ray, out hit))
       {
          GameObject ourObject = hit.collider.gameObject;

          string prefix = "spr_boards ";
          string txtNum = ourObject.transform.name.Remove(0, prefix.Length);
          int number = Int32.Parse(txtNum);

          Debug.Log ("this is object " + number);
       }
    }
 }
```

`int number` is the number from 1 to 5

Comment: this won't do sorry . But thank you

Comment: why not? this is how you get a number from the name

Comment: do you also need to get the object?

Comment: They have designated numbers sir.

Comment: i have edited the answer - now it also outputs the debug log string as you requested

Comment: I will try this sir

Comment: Where should I put this on my script

Comment: next to the `public void InstantiateObject()`

Comment: please upvote and accept the answer if it works. thank you.